# Multiple seaborn heatmaps plots to be saved as picture

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to get two heatmaps on next to each other on the same line. But the result I get from my code are blank white pictures.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(flights.shape[1], (flights.shape[0] + 2) // 2))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d")

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(1, (flights.shape[0] + 2) // 2))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights.sum(axis=1).to_frame(), annot=True, fmt="d")

fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig("myplot.png",)
```

The result I want to achieve is the result from this plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(flights.shape[1], (flights.shape[0] + 2) // 2))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d")
```

and this one:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(1, (flights.shape[0] + 2) // 2))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights.sum(axis=1).to_frame(), annot=True, fmt="d")
```

to be next to each other and save them as picture. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You want one single figure, right? Then first define a figure `plt.figure()` ***after*** that define the two subplots.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,  gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[flights.shape[1], 1]}, sharey=True, figsize=(flights.shape[1], (flights.shape[0] + 2) // 2))


sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", ax=ax1)
sns.heatmap(flights.sum(axis=1).to_frame(), annot=True, fmt="d", ax=ax2)

fig.savefig("myplot.png")
```